# SQL 2008 report manager not accessible

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a SQL 2008 developer edition with SSRS and the report manager is only available from the local machine. If I try to access it from any other machine I get challenged for my domain u/name and pwd 3 times and then the screen stays blank.

I have made changes to some config files (originals copied out) in order to get a 3rd party application to run but that is now uninstalled and the config files are all back to vanilla (originals copied back in)

I feel its something to do with authentication but am stuck ...

any suggestions welcomed

Jonathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just stumbled on the answer.

I changed the Report Server Service Account to use the built-in Local System account and its all accessible from remote browsers.

Anyone any ideas why?

Comment: Possibly because it wasn't running when you were logged out (if it was running under your account). If it isn't running under a service account, it may not be running at all except when that account is logged in, as opposed to a service running at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the SSRS Configuration (through the GUI) (Start - Microsoft SQL Server 2008 - Configuration Tools - Reporting Services Configuration Manager) and set it to allow connections from outside the box it is on.

Also don't forget that it's using domain credentials / local machine credentials, so if you're not on a domain, you'll have to provide credentials to log onto that machine (i.e. MACHINE1 where SSRS is installed, from MACHINE2, log on with MACHINE1\username and password for MACHINE1).

Or you may need to open up your SQL Server instance to permit connections from other boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but as you will see I managed to bump into the solution by accident shortly after posting!

Just for info, where in the Config Manager is the remote connections setting?

Comment: I actually don't think there's anything in there for SSRS 2008 for remote connections. I took a look after I posted that and I don't think that it's an option there (I thought it was in 2005, though I could be wrong). I may be getting that confused with SQL Surface Area Configuration (2005).